# kotlin how to get string into url parse

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I want to get the string from urldata.url to put into Uri.parse
so when I click it will take me to the webpage of that url

the code itself works fine but only the URI parse can't get the string from urldata

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: adapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int)
{

    val urldata : data = datalist[position]
    holder.name.text = urldata.name
    holder.url.text = urldata.url



    // cardview clicking link to the url
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(
        View.OnClickListener {
            startActivity(
                Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse()
                )
            )
        }
    )
}
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `setOnClickListener` like this:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    try {
        startActivity(
            Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(urldata.url)
            )
        )
    } catch (e: ParseException) { Log.e("onBindViewHolder", "Invalid URI") }
}
```

Comment: It didn't link me to that website in the URL though

Comment: Are you sure that the ParseException is not thrown? It may be an invalid URL

Comment: It's show nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(urldata.url);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Try adding this onClickListener